# How to make wx not block as focused window [Python]

Tags: multithreading, wxpython, pywin32

I made an overlay in wxpython which I use to display a bitmap on my computer. However, when I integrate it into an app that takes focus on a screen and moves my mouse, it blocks the app and never goes in the "apploop". If I comment the Overlay in the app constructor, the app works just fine but I wouldn't see the Overlay.

I tried threading the `wx_app.Mainloop` (I would comment `self.wx_app.MainLoop()`) and the apploop works fine but it now freezes the windows that's focused by the app so it's useless. Other processes like Chrome work fine.

How would I make the focused windows not blocked while having the overlay? I would need both of them at the same time.

Here's a simplified example of my code:

```
import win32gui, win32process, win32api
import wx
import threading

class App():
    def __init__(self) -> None:
        # Window focus
        hwnd = win32gui.FindWindow(None, 'Exact window name')
        win32gui.SetActiveWindow(hwnd)
        remote_thread, _ = win32process.GetWindowThreadProcessId(hwnd)
        win32process.AttachThreadInput(win32api.GetCurrentThreadId(), remote_thread, True)
        prev_handle = win32gui.SetFocus(hwnd)

        # Overlay
        self.wx_app = wx.App()
        self.overlay = Overlay()
        self.wx_app.MainLoop()
        # t = threading.Thread(target=self.wx_app.MainLoop)
        # t.start()

        self.apploop()

    def apploop(self):
        import time
        while True:
            print('Apploop running')
            time.sleep(5)
```

```
class Overlay(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self):
        style = ( wx.CLIP_CHILDREN | wx.STAY_ON_TOP | wx.NO_BORDER | wx.FRAME_SHAPED  )
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, None, title='Fancy', style = style)
        self.bitmap = wx.StaticBitmap(parent=self)
        self.SetSize( (320, 180) )
        self.SetPosition( (10,10) )
        self.SetBackgroundColour( [0,0,0,255] )
        self.SetTransparent( 200 )
        self.Show(True)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were almost there. The `wx.App` has to be started in the main Python thread and cannot run in `threading.Thread`. So **your** long-running-code will work when running `wx_app.MainLoop()` in the main thread and your payload in a `Thread`:

```py
        self.wx_app = wx.App()
        self.overlay = Overlay()
        t = threading.Thread(target=self.apploop)
        t.start()
        self.wx_app.MainLoop()
```

See at the end of [wx Wiki - LongRunningTasks](https://wiki.wxpython.org/LongRunningTasks) for a very simple example, mind the `wx.CallAfter` or other thread-safe Python objects to communicate between worker and main thread.

Comment: Thank you so much, I wouldn't have thought of doing that! That was the problem